# Python: generating tuples in a list

Tags: python

Is there an elegant/alternative way to do this:

```
allcolors = []
for Red in range(0,256):
    for Green in range(0,256):
        for Blue in range(0,256):
            allcolors.append((Red,Green,Blue))
```

I was thinking something like (Pseudo code) :

```
[Red for Red in [Green for Green in [Blue for Blue in range(0,256)]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
allcolors = [(Red,Green,Blue) for Red in range(0,256) for Green in range(0,256) for Blue in range(0,256)]
```

In [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), the `for ... in ...` clauses go in the same order as if they were for-loops.

---

Secondly, the 0's passed to `range` are redundant here since `range` starts at 0 by default. In other words, you can write the same thing more consicely like so:

```
allcolors = [(Red,Green,Blue) for Red in range(256) for Green in range(256) for Blue in range(256)]
```

---

Also, if you are on Python 2.x, you should use [`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead of `range`:

```
allcolors = [(Red,Green,Blue) for Red in xrange(256) for Green in xrange(256) for Blue in xrange(256)]
```

This is because `xrange` returns an [iterator](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#iterator) instead of constructing an unnecessary list like `range`.

---

Finally, the [convention](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) for Python variable names is that they be lowercase.  Meaning, `Red`, `Green`, and `Blue` *should* be named `red`, `green`, and `blue`. :)

Comment: better off using `xrange`.

Comment: @isedev - Well, I'll mention it.  However, we still do not know what version of Python the OP is using.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [*list comprehension*:](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
allcolors = [(r, g, b) for r in xrange(0, 256) for g in xrange(0, 256) for b in xrange(0, 256)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
allcolors = [ (Red,Green,Blue) for Red in range(0,256) for Green in range(0,256) for Blue in range(0,256) ]
```

You can transform your loop into a list comprehension by thinking about it like this:

```
[(Red,Green,Blue) for Red in range(0,256)
                     for Green in range(0,256)
                         for Blue in range(0,256) ]
```